# How to add x days to unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, unix-timestamp

I have this:

```
let currentTS = Math.floor(+new Date() / 1000)
```

and it works, it gives me the current date in a `unix timestamp`. But now I want to add 14 days to the unix timestamp.

How can I add 14 days to the unix timestamp, and return the unix timestamp with 14 days added to it?

Comment: if you're not intentionally trying to do date math, i'd use moment or luxon, its much easier to work with than manual math: https://momentjs.com/ . you'll be able to do things like `moment().add(14, 'days')`

Comment: @dufox-- even the [authors of moment.js recommends not using moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/). You should use a non-monolithic library such as [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) or [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compute how many seconds are in 14 days and add it?

```
Math.floor(+new Date() / 1000) + 14 * 24 * 60 * 60
```

Comment: You could use `Date.now()`  instead of `+new Date()` to skip the coercion.